# How to delete any specific line from a .txt file PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, file

I have a .txt file named **"calendarId.txt"**. I have a textbox named **"txtUpdateSearchBox"** and a button Delete. I want to ***take input from that textbox*** and if there is **anything in txt file that I inputted should be erased on Delete button click**. How to do that ?

---

Here is my Script

```js
$('#btnDelete').click(function() {
      if ($("#txtUpdateSearchBox").val() != '') {
        olddata = olddata.replace(',' + $("#txtUpdateSearchBox").val(), '');
        olddata = olddata.replace($("#txtUpdateSearchBox").val(), ''); //Code delete from txt file } });
```

Thanks In Advance .

Comment: This is not even PHP

Answer (score 0):

you need server side script for it cause `jQuery` or anything
on clientside do not have permissions to change anything at
serverside. For above you should have logic written in serverside
languages(PHP,Java,NodeJS...) and you can call it via `ajax` calls.

```
$('#btnDelete').click(function() {
    var myKeyVals = { delete : $("#txtUpdateSearchBox").val() } 
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "delete_txt.php",
      data: myKeyVals,
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(resultData) { alert("Delete Complete") },
      error: function(resultData) { alert("Error") }, 
});

});
```